# Query to extract initial of name

Tags: sql

```
SELECT t1.Number,  
       t1.LastName,  
       t1.Birthday,  
       t2.Number,  
       t2.LastName,  
       t2.Birthday 
FROM Employee t1, Employee t2 
WHERE t1.BirthDay = t2.Birthday
AND t1.EmpNo <> t2.EmpNo
```

Can someone help me to modify this, so it can get the initial of "Firstname". ( The table has Number,LastName, Birthday, Firstname)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.Number,
t1.LastName,
SUBSTRING(t1.FirstName, 1, 1) FirstInitial,
t1.Birthday,
t2.Number,
t2.LastName,
SUBSTRING(t2.FirstName, 1, 1) SecondInitial,
t2.Birthday
FROM Employee t1, Employee t2
WHERE t1.BirthDate = t2.Birthdate
AND t1.EmpNo <> t2.EmpNo
```

`SUBSTRING` is the function you're after

Answer (score 1):

In MySql you can use `LEFT(Firstname, 1)` or `SUBSTR(Firstname, 1, 1)`.
In MS-SQL you can use `LEFT(Firstname, 1)`.
In Oracle you can use `SUBSTR(Firstname, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  t1.Number,
  t1.LastName,
  LEFT(t1.FirstName, 1) FirstInitialWithLeft,
  t1.Birthday,
  t2.Number,
  t2.LastName,
  SUBSTRING(t2.FirstName, 1, 1) SecondInitialWithSubstring,
  t2.Birthday
FROM Employee t1, Employee t2
WHERE t1.BirthDate = t2.Birthdate
  AND t1.EmpNo <> t2.EmpNo
```